# nextcloud can't create an admin user

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, containers, nextcloud

error while trying to create the admin user:

```
Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'nextcloud'@'172.22.0.6' (using password: YES)
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  nextcloud-data:
  nextcloud-db:

networks:
  nginx_network:
    external: true

services:

  app:
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-data:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
    networks:
      - nginx_network
```

I couldn't find any similar problems with a solution that works for me and the docker compose seems okay to me

Comment: looks like you're trying to create the `admin` database user using the `nextcloud` database user. That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm trying to create a nextcloud admin using the db user via the nextcloud gui

Comment: yes, but you must have configured something incorrectly, because it tries to create that user using the `nextcloud` user, whereas I bet user management is reserved to `root`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller if I try to do it with the root user the same error appears with `'root'@'172.22.0.6'` instead of `'nextcloud'@'172.22.0.6'`

Comment: I think it isn't a permission error but something else with connecting to the data base

Comment: It **explicitly** says it's a permission error: "Access denied"

Comment: But it denies the permission even for the root user so it has to be something other that just  normal user not being able to create something

Comment: as said, you've not configured it correctly – probably wrong credentials.

Comment: The configuration is the one that i posted, the only difference is that i changed the `MYSQL_USER=nextcloud` to `MYSQL_USER=root` and the error is as stated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution that worked for me:

1. changed database container's name
2. deleted all the volumes

**DO NOT SET THE USER AS ROOT** normal user is enough

(also this error shows up if you mistype your credentials between containers)

Comment: Can you clarify this answer? What in the docker-config.yml file needs to change?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message at least up to `SQLSTATE[HY000]`.
For me the solution was to put the IP-Adress listed for the maria-db container in the portainer.io GUI in the field `host` without a port. I also removed and added again the Nextcloud container and Maria-db stack (which automatically adds a container), but I do not think that that did the trick. I followed [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/raspberry-pi-install-nextcloud-openmediavault-nas/)
guide.